# Declaring Variables in Blocks, Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, queue, block

thread my project but using queue's and blocks but I get an error when I try to queue the code. I know that you cannot queue UI elements in blocks so I am avoiding that but the error I get is when I do call a UI element outside of the block it says that the variable is not declared although it is declared inside the block. Here is the code. The code is a UITableView method and it just takes an array sorts it and displays it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Create an instance of the cell
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Photo Description"];

if(!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Photo Description"];

// set properties on the cell to prepare if for displaying
//top places returns an array of NSDictionairy objects, must get object at index and then object for key

//Lets queue this
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("FlickerPhotoQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

//lets sort the array

NSArray* unsortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self.brain class] topPlaces]] ;
//This will sort the array
NSSortDescriptor* descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"_content" ascending:YES];
NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];                                   
NSArray *sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSString * cellTitle = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:self.location] objectForKey:@"_content"]; 

NSRange cellRange = [cellTitle rangeOfString:@","];

NSString * cellMainTitle = [cellTitle substringToIndex:cellRange.location];

});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);  

//Claims that this are not declared since they are declared in the block
cell.textLabel.text = cellMainTitle;
//This isnt declared either
NSString* cellSubtitle = [cellTitle substringFromIndex:cellRange.location +2];

cell.detailTextLabel.text =  cellSubtitle;
self.location++;
return cell;
}
```

I managed to get the program to work by moving the dispatch release to the very end of the block of code and then having the UI interface be declared in the main thread by calling dispatch_get_main_queue. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Mind you, I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think you're having a scope issue. Whenever you put anything between {}, all variables declared within expire at it's end. Furthermore, I believe that blocks work a lot like functions. Long story short, try declaring cellMainTitle outside of the block, set it inside of the block and then use it later. This may solve your problem (and maybe cause another, called concurrency)

Comment: Concurrency is what you are doing: To run multiple paths of code at the same time via threading, either by manually dealing with threads or using the GCD.

Comment: Yeah you cant do that but more importantly why are you sorting an array in cellForRowAtIndexPath - create and sort your array before you populate the table - this method is only to get the contents of one cell.  And get rid of the GCD block, its likely making your UI even slower in this case.

Comment: yeah i know my UI is pretty slow atm because of this

Comment: and what you mean U cant do that?

Answer (score 6):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you are declaring a variable inside a block and trying to use it outside.

That won't work. Variables declared inside blocks are limited to the block's scope. If you create them inside the block, you are limited to using them in the block and you can't use them anywhere else.

A better idea will be to create the variable you want to use outside the block. If you want to modify the variable in the block, use the __block keyword.

```
__block UITableViewCell *someCell;
//__block tells the variable that it can be modified inside blocks.
//Some generic block
^{
//initialize the cell here.
}
```

Comment: How would U recommend I declare these variables then to use in a block?

Comment: I just edited my answer to add those details. It's a bit lazy in syntax right now (I'm college right now) but it tell you about the __block modified which you will need.

Comment: Of course, this is going to likely cause other problems, as `cellMainTitle`, etc. probably won't have their values set properly by the time they are used (in `cell.textLabel.text = cellMainTitle;`, etc.).

Comment: Yeah that's something to watch out for. Maybe the best idea will be load all the data someplace else instead of trying to load it dynamically with cellForRowAtIndexPath. Not sure what Terrel Gibson is trying to do though, so I can't offer any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The variable being defined inside the block is local to that block and thus does not exist outside of it. You can pre-define these variables before entering the block, however this is entering a specialized territory and requires use of an extension when defining these variables. Look up "__block" storage type in Organizer. I did not spend too much time reviewing your code to know if this is sane advice given the details.